# How to log stack trace on node.js process error event

Tags: node.js, error-handling

My node process is dying and I can't seem to log to a file when the process exits. It is a long running process invoked directly with `node index.js`:

```
// index.js
const fs = require('fs');

exports.getAllCars = (process => {
    if (require.main === module) {
        console.log(`Running process: ${process.getgid()}.`);
        let out = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/process.log`);

        // trying to handle process events here:
        process.on('exit', code => out.write(`Exit: ${code}`));

        return require('./lib/cars').getAllCars();
    } else {
        return require('./lib/cars').getAllCars;
    }
})(process);
```

Also tried creating event handlers for `error`, `uncaughtException`. Nothing works when killing my process manually (with `kill {pid}`). The file `process.log` is created but nothing is there. Do writeable streams require a `stream.end()` to be called on completion?

Comment: `kill $PID` sends a SIGTERM, so try adding a [signal handler](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) for those.

Comment: Well, I was just using ``kill {pid}`` to test. My real use-case is when the process just dies without any error logged anywhere. I haven't had this happen since I put the error handling in there. Usually the process dies unexpectedly after ~4 hrs.

Comment: If it dies without any errors being logged, my guess would be there's an outside reason for the process being killed (for instance, the OOM killer on Linux).

Comment: Of course now that I have handlers in place for ``exit``, ``error`` and ``uncaughtException``, the process is running fine... ``¯\_(ツ)_/¯``

Answer (score 7):

According to Node.js documentation:

> The 'exit' event is emitted when the Node.js process is about to exit
>   as a result of either:
>
> - The `process.exit()` method being called explicitly.
> - The Node.js event loop no longer having any additional work to perform.

So, if you start a process that should never end, it will never trigger.

Also, writable streams do not require to be closed:

> If `autoClose`(an option from `createWriteStream`) is set to `true` (default
>   behavior) on error or end the file descriptor will be closed
>   automatically.

however, the `createWriteStream` function opens the file with flag `'w'` by default, which means that the file will be overwritten every time (maybe this is the reason why you always see it empty). I suggest to use

```
fs.appendFileSync(file, data)
```

Here are the events that want to listen:

```
//catches ctrl+c event
//NOTE:
//If SIGINT has a listener installed, its default behavior will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit).
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    fs.appendFileSync(`${__dirname}/process.log`, `Received SIGINT\n`);
    process.exit()
});

//emitted when an uncaught JavaScript exception bubbles
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    fs.appendFileSync(`${__dirname}/process.log`, `Caught exception: ${err}\n`);
});

//emitted whenever a Promise is rejected and no error handler is attached to it
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    fs.appendFileSync(`${__dirname}/process.log`, `Unhandled Rejection at: ${p}, reason: ${reason}\n`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put the code in a try catch block to find out whether its the code or some external cause which results in program termination.
and then check the log after the event...

```
try {
  //your code 
}catch(e) {
  console.log(e.stack);
}
```